# discordjs v12 cannot read property roles of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot with the newest version v12, and im facing an issue when it comes to adding 
a role to a member.

I know that the User object does not have any roles, but member should have as the documentation says.
This is how I get my user:

`let member = msg.mentions.members.first();`

This is how I add my role:

`member.roles.add(role);`

Though, im facing this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
```

context:

```
if(args[0] == 'blacklist'){
                if(args[1] != null){
                    if(args[2] != null){
                    let member = msg.mentions.members.first();
                    let role = (msg.member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'muted'));
                    member.roles.add(role);


                    } else {
                        msg.channel.send('> Error: missing reason');
                    }
                } else {
                    msg.channel.send('> Error: missing userID');
                }
            }`
```

Comment: is 'msg' the parameter from your `message` event?

Comment: yes, and it should work, right?

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you please provide some extra context so we can help you find the issue?

Comment: @PedroFracassi done

Comment: It still seems to work for me. Are you sure this error is related to that bit of code? Could you also post the full stack trace so we have even more context?

Comment: I got a quickfix: it seemed to be an issue caused by the arguments. Weird error, somehow got it working. closed.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your fix as an answer? Someone with the same problem might find this page future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add check, if no mentions in message.

```js
if(args[0] == 'blacklist'){
    if(args[1] != null){
        if(args[2] != null){
            let member = msg.mentions.members.first();
            if (!member) return msg.reply('Pls mention a member')
            let role = (msg.member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'muted'));
            member.roles.add(role);

        } else {
            msg.channel.send('> Error: missing reason');
        }
    } else {
        msg.channel.send('> Error: missing userID');
    }
}
```